# Calculate product of index values in list of list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of list of frequencies (see example). How can I get the product of all the nth members of the list. 
For example:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6] 
output = [4,10,18]
```

How can I accomplish this if the length of the list is unknown. Please answer with a pythonic way, I appreciate the help!

Sample Data:

```
[
 [0.8507462686567164, 0.14925373134328357], [0.9870967741935484, 
 0.012903225806451613], [0.5833333333333334, 0.4166666666666667], 

 [0.4791666666666667, 0.5208333333333334], [0.9379084967320261, 
 0.06209150326797386], [0.9657320872274143, 0.03426791277258567], 

 [0.9914529914529915, 0.008547008547008548], [0.9050279329608939, 
 0.09497206703910614], [0.7660944206008584, 0.23390557939914164]
]
```

output:

```
[product of 1st elements, product of 2nd elements, product of n elements]
```

Comment: Use the `zip` function.

Comment: Do the required length checks or error checks and you should be able to just do something as follows `[a*b for a,b in zip(l1,l2)]`

Comment: `print([x * y for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2=[4,5,6]
>>> [x * y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
[4, 10, 18]
```